# How to write correct field criteria to get rid of the 'enter parameter value' erro?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

PICTURE OF QUERY :

[image]

I'm plotting graphs for 10 machines (machine 1, machine 2,...) performance - 
average vs date graph.

User shall select the machine from a combobox (i made the values obtained from query, or should I make it from the table?) and set it to contain unique values only.

After selecting the machine, user shall click OK button. and a graph of the selected machine should be displayed in a new form.

Problem is, every time I click OK, it prompts me with the ENTER PARAMETER VALUE `Forms!ViewReport!Combo9`.

After I enter "machine 1" in the ENTER PARAMETER VALUE, it displays the graph correctly. I am expecting the graph to be displayed directly without the error.

Comment: Form with this combobox is open?

Comment: Oh i made it be closed when OK button is clicked.

Comment: Is other form bound? Is it opened filtered to the specific machine? Is that query datasource for the graph? Shouldn't graph reference field on its own form? Edit question to post OK button code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dialog appears because the query has no access to the field Combo9. Probably your form is not open or `ViewReport` is a subform, in this case, the reference to Combo9 should be different. Check, for instance, [this giude](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm) for controls references.

But the most reliable method is to create a public function in the standard module, which should return the value from the desired form's field. It can check if the form is open and return the default value if the form is not available or the value is not selected. This function can be used in queries as criteria or in calculated fields.

Comment: they combobox is inside the viewreport form and when ok button is clicked. the viewreport will be closed and another form "graph" will be opened and a graph will be displayed on the form. they are two separate  forms. what do u mean by 'form is not open' ?

Comment: If you close the ViewReport form by clicking OK, combobox becomes not available for the query and it asks to enter the parameter. In this case, you'd better create a public function in the standard module, which should return the value selected in combobox, for instance from a global or static variable. This variable can be updated when the user selects the value in combobox.